# Spark 1.1.0 on cdh5.1.3 does not work in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I am having CDH 5.1 (Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.1.3) installed on my cluster, version:

I have installed and configured a prebuilt version of Spark 1.1.0 (Apache Version), built for hadoop 2.3 on my cluster.

when I run the Pi example in the ‘client mode’, it runs successfully, but it fails in the ‘yarn-cluster’ mode. The spark job is successfully submitted, but fails after polling the application master for sometime:

---

```
More Logs:
Application application_1415193640322_0016 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1415193640322_0016_000002. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.getRemoteException(RPCUtil.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagerImpl.java:710)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ContainerManagementProtocolPBServiceImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ContainerManagementProtocol$ContainerManagementProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ContainerManagementProtocol.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.security.ContainerTokenIdentifier.readFields(ContainerTokenIdentifier.java:151)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.decodeIdentifier(Token.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.utils.BuilderUtils.newContainerTokenIdentifier(BuilderUtils.java:262)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagerImpl.java:696)
... 10 more

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:99)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:118)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:249)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException): java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.getRemoteException(RPCUtil.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagerImpl.java:710)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ContainerManagementProtocolPBServiceImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ContainerManagementProtocol$ContainerManagementProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ContainerManagementProtocol.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.security.ContainerTokenIdentifier.readFields(ContainerTokenIdentifier.java:151)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.decodeIdentifier(Token.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.utils.BuilderUtils.newContainerTokenIdentifier(BuilderUtils.java:262)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagerImpl.java:696)
... 10 more

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1409)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1362)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.startContainers(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
... 5 more
. Failing the application.



When I go to node Manager logs:

Log Type: stderr
Log Length: 87
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher
```

---

Can you please suggest any solution.Do you think I should compile the spark code on my cluster. Or should I use Spark provided with CDH5.1.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`spark-shell` does not work with spark yarn-cluster mode. You should add `--master yarn-client`

Example:

`path/to/pyspark --master yarn-client`